# Opening Android SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm currently developing an android app with eclipse. I have many activities in the package. Each activities need to connect to the database. I put the open(); and close(); database method in each class. What I want to ask is, is there any implementation to open and close database just once, in order to avoid opening and closing database in each class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), [cursor loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), and of course Database helper.

I'd be very careful about starting off with raw queries in your app. SQLite does not have multithreaded support and you can easily get yourself into database locking hell.